Turn on Bluetooth automatically when Android Auto/AAWireless is detected
I have an AAWireless, and I would like to make Android Auto automatically connect and start (i.e. without any input from my side).
This is working without any problem if I keep Bluetooth and WiFi always on on my smartphone, but I would prefer to keep Bluetooth off, since normally I don't use it (while I don't mind to keep WiFi on, since I use it regularly).
To be clear: I understand that Bluetooth is needed in order for AAW to work, what I would like is a way to turn it on automatically when AA is detected. In other words I would like the same behavior as wired AA: even if the Bluetooth is off, when I connect the smartphone to the USB cable in my car, it turns on the Bluetooth.
When I bought AAW I was thinking there would be the same mechanism, just not through the wire but through the WiFi, but I can not find out a way to do it.
I noticed that it looks likes it first need to connect through Bluetooth, since without it it is not able to connect through WiFi (it establishes some sort of "ad-hoc" connection, if I look on the list of my known WiFi network, AAW WiFi does not appear).
But even so, maybe there is a mechanism that could turn on the Bluetooth automatically if the specific AAW WiFi network is detected (nor connected)?

I found this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#enable() and it looks that with API 33, it is not possible to turn on/off BT automatically, at least for "third" app (no idea for "system" app). Please correct me if I'm wrong.
